# Slowing down the bootstrap spinner

Tags: animation, bootstrap-4, spinner

I am currently working with bootstrap and using the grow spinner:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/spinners/

Do you know if there is any way to control the speed and slow down the animation ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the css property `animation-duration`.
For example, to slow the animation down, increase the animation-duration:

```
.spinner-border {
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```